# Ошибка в консоли Git

Tags: git, github, git-push

```
$ git pull
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... "C:\Users\dmitr\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Sublime Text Build 3207 x64\sublime_text.exe" -w: C:\Users\dmitr\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Sublime Text Build 3207 x64\sublime_text.exe: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor '"C:\Users\dmitr\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Sublime Text Build 3207 x64\sublime_text.exe" -w'.
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.
```

Я давно скачивал Sublime text (просто папку скачал на рабочий стол, без установки), потом удалил. А сейчас пишет, что в нём открыт файл... Как исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sublime_text.exe прописал себя как редактор для комментов.
надо поменять редактор. например так

```
git config --global core.editor "notepad"
```

или любой другой. почитайте тут https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/associating-text-editors-with-git